# Filtering SQL query by unique id and earliest dates that are in the future

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that returns the correct data, but I would like to filter it.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Reg_Master.id, dbo.Cart_Programs.cartid, dbo.Reg_Master.F_ID,   dbo.BlockPeriod.profileid, dbo.Reg_Master.FirstName, 
                      dbo.Reg_Master.LastName, dbo.BlockPeriod.startdate, dbo.Cart_Programs.blockid
FROM         dbo.Cart_Programs LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Reg_Master ON dbo.Cart_Programs.cartid = dbo.Reg_Master.cartid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.BlockPeriod ON dbo.Cart_Programs.blockid = dbo.BlockPeriod.id
WHERE     (dbo.BlockPeriod.profileid = xxx) AND (dbo.Reg_Master.F_ID = xxxx)
ORDER BY dbo.BlockPeriod.startdate
```

For each `dbo.Reg_Master.id`, I would like to return only the earliest `dbo.BlockPeriod.startdate` (that is today or later - in other words ignoring dates that have already passed) for each `dbo.Reg_Master.id`, I cannot seem to get it formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, TOP 100 Percent does nothing, the optimizer will just ignore it. 
Also, your left joins do not serve any purpose because your `WHERE` condition, so I have edited the SQL to use an `inner join` + `cross apply` vs an `outer join` + `outer apply`.

If I understand you correctly for each `Reg_Master` record, you want at most 1 record from `BlockPeriod`, where that 1 record is the closest date that is greater than today's date.

If so, then what you are looking for is an `APPLY` table operator combined with `TOP (1)` as shown below:

**UPDATED**:

```
SELECT Reg_Master.id, 
       Cart_Programs.cartid, 
       Reg_Master.F_ID,   
       T.profileid, 
       Reg_Master.FirstName, 
       Reg_Master.LastName, 
       T.startdate, 
       Cart_Programs.blockid
FROM Cart_Programs 
JOIN Reg_Master  ON Cart_Programs.cartid  = Reg_Master.cartid
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM BlockPeriod
    WHERE BlockPeriod.id = Cart_Programs.blockid
      AND BlockPeriod.profileid = xxx AND Reg_Master.F_ID = xxxx 
      AND BlockPeriod.startdate >= GETDATE()
 ORDER BY BlockPeriod.startdate ASC 
) AS T
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in this example. it does not filter the results at all and the startdate value is NULL for all records. Any other ideas?

Comment: OK. It is still returning 13 records, I only need 2, 1 for each Reg_Master.id. Your help is so appreciated.

Comment: @resnantmedia - this means that you have a 1 to many relationship from `Cart_Programs` to `Reg_Master`. For each record in `Cart_Programs` you have 1 or more records in Reg_Master. I bet you out of the 13 records there are 13 Unique Reg_Master.id

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the result set: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/655368/Screen%20Shot%202012-01-26%20at%2011.39.49%20PM.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7090/discussion-between-resonantmedia-and-j-cooper)